# vagrant の仮想マシンの、プライベート IP の一覧を取得したい

Tags: vagrant

Vagrant のマシンをいくつも構築していくと、どの VM がどれだったのか、ぱっとわからなくなってきます。例えば、それぞれのマシンと、それが紐づいている (`private_network` で指定される) プライベートIP の一覧が、表示できると便利だと考えました。

これを実現する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7869 で enhancement, milestone 1.9 になったので、たぶん現状ではできないんだと思います。